# Override width of part of my CSS vertical accordeon

Tags: html, css, width, transition

I wanted to create a pure CSS vertical accordeon with 3 divs, with the middle one always keeping its width (40%). In the initial state, my 3 divs have to be like this :

- First div : 30% of width
- Second div : 40% of width
- Last div : 30% of   width

When the first or the last div is hovered, it must expand to a width of 58%.

However, the last div don't expand like I want, due to the initial width of my item set to 30%:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.donslide {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.donslide .item {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 30%;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out all;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
  background: black;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 58%;
}
```

```html
<div class="donslide">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If I remove the width setting of my item, everything works like a charm but the transition :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.donslide {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.donslide .item {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ddd;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out all;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
  background: black;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 58%;
}
```

```html
<div class="donslide">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make my accordeon work while keeping the sweet transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex box is the your savior, you can take advantage of the flex-grow property to 
get the desired effect

See code snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.donslide {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.donslide .item {
  background: #ddd;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out all;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0%;
  flex-grow:1;

}

.center {
  width: 40%;
  background: black;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="donslide">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do ! Thank you very much for your help, I will dig this flexbox property !